# Bootstrap nav-tabs Disabled and enabled

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to disabled one of my tab when the page is loaded.
After the user select a iten, it's necessary enable that tab and simulate a click on it.
The disabled event it's work for me, but when I remove disabled class that my "li" the event click in this tab not do nothing...

```html
<ul id="tab-principal" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="active" id="navPesquisa"><a data-target="#divPesquisa" data-toggle="tab">Pesquisa</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id="navDadosDocumento"><a href="#divDetalhes" aria-controls="divDetalhes" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Dados do Documento</a></li>
</ul>
```

Disabling the tab

```html
// Desabilita a aba de dados do aço interno
$('#navDadosDocumento').attr('class', 'disabled');
```

Enabling and click in the tab

```html
$('#navDadosDocumento').removeAttr('class', 'disabled');
$('a[href="#divDetalhes"]').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

`.removeAttr()` takes only one parameter, the attribute to remove.
To add and remove classes, jQuery provides `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/
https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

So to make your code work, replace

```
$('#navDadosDocumento').removeAttr('class', 'disabled');
```

with

```
$('#navDadosDocumento').removeClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#navDadosDocumento').attr('class', 'disabled');
  });
  $( "#divDetalhes" ).click(function() {
    $('#navDadosDocumento').removeAttr('class', 'disabled');
    $('a[href="#divDetalhes"]').trigger('click');
  });
```

**Also check here**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#navDadosDocumento').attr('class', 'disabled');
});
$( "#divDetalhes" ).click(function() {
    $('#navDadosDocumento').removeAttr('class', 'disabled');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul id="tab-principal" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="active" id="navPesquisa"><a data-target="#divPesquisa" data-toggle="tab">Pesquisa</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id="navDadosDocumento"><a href="#divDetalhes" aria-controls="divDetalhes" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Dados do Documento</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry, but I'm not understanding... Will I enable the tab when the user click it on?